# Can't plot time series with seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, data-visualization

I have a dataset that is a set of measurements in different time labels, such as:

| Sample | t1 | t2 | ... | tn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.2 | 0.4 | ... | 1.2 |
| 2 | 0.1 | 2.0 | ... | 0.5 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | 8.2 |

I want to create a lineplot with confidence interval like this:

[image]

I want these time labels (t1, t2, ... , tn) in x-axis. But looking at the seaborn documentation, i must pass an `x` argument to the `sns.lineplot()` function. I am a little confused and couldn't figure out how to structure data.

Any hints would be welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if that's a pandas dataframe, `x` is `df['t1']` or whatever... and you first have to calculate the stdev/error... can you post some code so you can replicate?

Comment: @DervinThunk you actually don't. That's the whole point of `seaborn`.

Comment: May be helpful... http://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/data_structure.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a random sample and played around with it.

Data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "sample": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
    "t1": np.random.randn(7),
    "t2": np.random.randn(7),
    "t3": np.random.randn(7),
    "t4": np.random.randn(7),
    "t5": np.random.randn(7),
    "t6": np.random.randn(7),
    "t7": np.random.randn(7),
})
```

In order to use `sns.lineplot` directly without calculating standard error by hand, I made a transformation to `df`:

```
df_long = pd.melt(df, id_vars="sample", value_vars="t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6 t7".split())
df_long["sample"] = 1
df_long.head()
```

I also set the `sample` to be a single same value `1` so that seaborn considers all data to be from the same pool.

Then plotting is straight forward:

```
sns.lineplot(data=df_long, x="variable", y="value", hue="sample")
```

And you get something like:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Seaborn is best when you have long form data. So you should melt your data to pass in seaborn:

```
sns.lineplot(data=df.melt('Sample'), x='variable', y='value')
```